# How to find out if a user is using screen reader on my website

Tags: drupal, accessibility, drupal-8, screen-readers

Is there are a way (a library) with which a web page can detect a screen reader being used on it? This can be just for a reporting/analytics purpose.

*PS: A Drupal 8 website.*

Comment: You can do this, but probably shouldn't try because in coding MANY things are possible, though not advisable. In Chrome, for instance, if a user has ChromeVox Spoken Feedback installed as an addon, you will have a window.cvox JavaScript object you can test for. Other addons and browsers will likely have their own window.object to detect, but finding and testing for ALL of them is going to be nearly impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Screen readers operate as an application on the computer - this would be similar to trying to find out if someone viewing your website also had their calculator open - it is a privacy restriction. Also many of these users may be using Voiceover or Talkback on their mobile devices and there is no way to detect that either.

Your website should instead strive to follow web standards and work equally for all users.

I'm also curious as to what your specific goal is in detecting this, as screen readers are only one part of the accessibility tools that many people use - and focusing on just the screen reader user will not make your site accessible.

Comment: So, you're wrong and I wish people wouldn't post such "no way, it's not possible" answers on stackoverflow. In coding, MANY things are possible, though maybe not advisable. In Chrome, for instance, if a user has ChromeVox Spoken Feedback installed as an addon, you will have a window.cvox object you can test for. Other addons and browsers will likely have their own window.object to detect, but finding and testing for ALL of them is going to be nearly impossible.

Comment: @ChrisN The question is phrased in a sense which implies it's trying to detect the presence of a screen reader *in general*, not to enumerate a list of the ones known to be detectable... and there's no reason for the ones which operate purely externally to the browser (via the same APIs used to make other applications accessible) to be detectable that way.

Comment: Detecting a screen reader (even it was possible) is a RED FLAG for accessibility. DON'T DO IT!!!!

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't. Definitely not.

One thing you can do is detecting if a user uses his mouse. This does not mean that he uses a screenreader or that he doesn't but is quite an indicator (but this should be categorized as "keyboard only users" not "screenreader users"). And that's, in my opinion, a question more interesting than knowing if a user uses a screenreader.

There are a lot of discussions about the wrongdoing of detecting screenreaders :

- [On Screen Reader Detection](http://adrianroselli.com/2014/03/on-screen-reader-detection.html)
- [Detecting screen readers in analytics, pros and cons](https://www.powermapper.com/blog/accessibility-analytics/)

Comment: a comment on your edit regarding 'keyboard only' users: Many visually impaired users might also use a mouse. I know some blind users who use a mouse to jump to a general area on a page as it can be faster than trying to find it via keyboard (particularly on poorly coded websites). Also, viewing a page on mobile devices can add an additional obstacle to this keyboard metric as many of those users will never use a keyboard to navigate. Many users also navigate form fields by keyboard, which would need to be considered.

Comment: Also, there are many users who are sighted and also rely on screen readers, such as those with ADD/ADHD and illiterate users - many of whom would also use a mouse.

Comment: @Skerrvy You're perfectly right. For that reason, we can detect mouse/touchscreen/keyboard users but it won't give any information about the use or not of a screenreader, nor that it will give us the deficience they suffer or not, if any.

Comment: So, you're wrong and I wish people wouldn't post such "you can't, definitely not" answers on stackoverflow. In coding, MANY things are possible, though maybe not advisable. In Chrome, for instance, if a user has ChromeVox Spoken Feedback installed as an addon, you will have a window.cvox object you can test for. Other addons and browsers will likely have their own window.object to detect, but finding and testing for ALL of them is going to be nearly impossible.

Comment: @ChrisN This question is about screenreaders (using system Accessibility API), not about one browser plugin (interacting with the DOM).